# Pycharm: Run Django from virtual env

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have a Django project in Pycharm with a virtualenv named venv

My Terminal path is:

```
(venv) C:\projects\Django\deya>
```

I install my packages inside this virtualenv.

The problem is that when I run project from Pycharm run icon, I am getting errors like:

```
No module named 'django_tables2'
```

The command that Pycharm running is:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Users\kostas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe C:/projects/Django/deya/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
```

My project runs fine from Terminal command line, inside virtualenv:

```
(venv) C:\projects\Django\deya>python manage.py runserver
```

Can you help me setup the configuration of my project to run from Pycharm run console?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is complaining about not finding `django-tables2` module.

Did you install `django-tables2` module in your virutalenv

```
pip install django-tables2
```

The installation instruction for the module can be found [here](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/installation.html).

Further, this must be installed from within your activated `virtualenv`

**Update after your comment:**

Pycharm is picking the Python located at:
C:\Users\kostas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe

This does not look like python from a `virtualenv`

Link for changing this configuration provided in the comment.

Comment: yes I did , with success. I have the same problem with other packages. `(venv) C:\projects\Django\deya>python manage.py runserver` executes fine

Comment: In that case your pycharm is not configured to use python from your virtualenv. Have you configured it something like this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html

Comment: I had 2 interpreters in Phycharms. One looked in my virtualenv (Python 3.6) and the other was  C:\Users\kostas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe. Pycharms always used the 2nd interpreter. I had set up Phycharms to use the virtualenv interpreter but it used the 2nd. I had to delete 2nd interpreter from list to work. Maybe it is a path issue

Comment: Do I always have to have one only interpreter or something goes wrong with my configuration?

Comment: AFAIK, you can only have one interpreter per PyCharm project.

Answer (score 2):

Open PyCharm settings and search for "project interpreter", click on the gear icon, select "Add Local", in the dialog select "Existing environment" and point to your virtualenvs "python.exe". After closing the dialog ensure that your virtualenv is the selected project interpreter, close the settings and try running your app again.